# How to avoid repeating "method A" in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, redundancy

I try to say that the next example explain the idea my new method. However, I just repeat some words which make my sentence hard to follow.

Here is my try:

> To simplify the idea of method A, the following example shows how to build a new model using method A.

I repeat "method A". How can I write my sentence in a good way?

Thanks you so much

Comment: Why complicate things? The simplest way would just be to say/write *...how to build a new model using **it***. The referent of ***it*** is contextually obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure "simplify" is the right word for this context.  Do you mean "demonstrate"?  Also, I would recommend not picking an answer too quickly, as it may discourage others from giving you good alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To simplify the idea of method A, the following example shows how to
>   build a new model using this method.

Answer (score 3):

> The following example demonstrates how to build a model by using Method A.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest, and least repetitive, way of expressing the idea is to use the pronoun *it*:

> To simplify the idea of method A, the following example shows how to build a new model using **it**.

This prevents you from repeating either *method* or *A*.